# Can I process a single multispectral image with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have images of weeds taken using RedEdge on a drone and want to process these to find a point of difference. I have reflectance panel images. Can QGIS do this for these "Single shots" rather than an ortho?

Comment: What sensor are you working with?

Comment: Are all the images captured from the same point with the same instrument  so that they overlap perfectly without further processing?

Comment: I used the RedEdge M with no DLS. As a proof of concept I am taking a few "single" shots above a small plot containing the weeds. I would now like to process even one shot containing the five images of different band widths so I can establish whether a particular combination might make it easier to identify that weed.